# Login con Google (Android Studio)

Tags: android, login

no soy programador pero me interesa bastante el tema. He estado guiándome con tutoriales en youtube, principalmente [Login Google en Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3aemJ9eAAA&t=26s). Pero al tratar de probar la app con una cuenta válida de gmail no me permite entrar a la "main activity" y aparece el mensaje toast que utilicé cuando no se inicia sesión.

Agradecería saber cuál es mi error u omisión.

```
package app.livup.com.livup;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private SignInButton signInButton;

    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            goMainScreen();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
>     03-03 02:05:15.439 2525-2525/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>     03-03 02:05:15.440 2525-2525/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
>     03-03 02:05:15.545 2525-2525/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.livup.com.livup-1/lib/x86
>     03-03 02:05:15.566 2525-2525/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping
> initialization.
>     03-03 02:05:15.577 2525-2525/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping
> initialization.
>     03-03 02:05:15.638 2525-2525/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
>     03-03 02:05:15.638 2525-2525/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>     03-03 02:05:15.662 2525-2525/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app app.livup.com.livup
>     03-03 02:05:15.698 2525-2525/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
>     03-03 02:05:15.700 2525-2525/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for app.livup.com.livup
>     03-03 02:05:16.021 2525-2525/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
> android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
> would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>     03-03 02:05:16.037 2525-2525/? V/FA: onActivityCreated
>     03-03 02:05:16.186 2525-2525/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
>     03-03 02:05:16.196 2525-2525/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
>     03-03 02:05:16.196 2525-2525/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
>     03-03 02:05:16.223 2525-2525/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
> /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000005/n/x86
>     03-03 02:05:16.450 2525-2525/? D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false false
>     03-03 02:05:16.460 2525-2525/app.livup.com.livup D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true
> {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaa$zza@cb05238}
>     03-03 02:05:16.478 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Using measurement service
>     03-03 02:05:16.478 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     03-03 02:05:16.479 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 14347
>     03-03 02:05:16.538 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup D/FA: Connected to remote service
>     03-03 02:05:16.539 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
>     03-03 02:05:16.671 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>     03-03 02:05:16.671 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>     03-03 02:05:16.742 2525-2525/app.livup.com.livup W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int
> android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
> boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
> in android.widget.ListView
>     03-03 02:05:16.802 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup E/EGL_emulation: tid 2658: eglSurfaceAttrib(1178): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
>     03-03 02:05:16.802 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa46ff200,
> error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
>     03-03 02:05:21.579 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>     03-03 02:05:25.395 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8916
>     03-03 02:05:25.396 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Using measurement service
>     03-03 02:05:25.397 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>     03-03 02:05:25.405 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Activity paused, time: 23263
>     03-03 02:05:25.412 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
>     03-03 02:05:25.414 2525-2525/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: onActivityCreated
>     03-03 02:05:25.414 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=8916, _sc=LoginActivity,
> _si=8222527634204196242}]
>     03-03 02:05:25.514 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup E/EGL_emulation: tid 2658: eglSurfaceAttrib(1178): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
>     03-03 02:05:25.514 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa46ff2a0,
> error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
>     03-03 02:05:25.528 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Using measurement service
>     03-03 02:05:25.528 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     03-03 02:05:25.528 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Using measurement service
>     03-03 02:05:25.528 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     03-03 02:05:25.529 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 23304
>     03-03 02:05:25.529 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 94
>     03-03 02:05:25.529 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Using measurement service
>     03-03 02:05:25.530 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     03-03 02:05:25.530 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Activity paused, time: 23384
>     03-03 02:05:25.585 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup D/FA: Connected to remote service
>     03-03 02:05:25.586 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>     03-03 02:05:30.440 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 28307
>     03-03 02:05:30.525 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup E/EGL_emulation: tid 2658: eglSurfaceAttrib(1178): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
>     03-03 02:05:30.525 2525-2658/app.livup.com.livup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa53a0dc0,
> error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
>     03-03 02:05:35.442 2525-2592/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Puede por problemas en las versiones del Google Play Services, puedes hacer que muestre un mensaje en el siguiente método: @Override public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) { Log.d("MIAPP", connectionResult.getErrorMessage()); } Y así tener el error exacto del problema.

Comment: Que mensaje obtienes? Algún mensaje en el LogCat? realiza lo que comenta Daniel Alvarez en su respuesta y comenta que mensaje se desplego.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Implementé el código, pero no sé donde puedo ver el log de errores

Comment: Ya encontré el log. Esto salé en el logcat

`03-03 01:22:49.520 2452-2600/app.livup.com.livup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ef2b5e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH`

`03-03 01:22:54.433 2452-3765/app.livup.com.livup V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`

Comment: Que otros datos mas te aparecen? necesitamos encontrar si apareció el tag que pusiste, si lo dejaste como el código que puse debemos buscar un MIAPP

Comment: No encuentro el tag en el logcat

Comment: Estaba pensando que quizás sea un problema de versión del google services

Comment: Lo que agregaste no indica ningun problema, revisa si aparece texto en rojo indicando un problema, existen demasiads razones por las cuales no funcionaría iniciando por tal vez no haber habilitado la API.

Comment: Esta mañana estuve probando la API para autentificarse con Google y tu código parece bueno, a mi me dio un problema con la clave SSH1 que cree otra y creo que mi problema está en mi cuenta de GoogleAPIs, ¿tengo que generar un oAuth o algo similar? La única vez que lo usé fue para probar la API de youtube y ahora el código funciona pero me devuelve siempre un error al intentar conectar, me quedé atascado ahí. Lo comento por si puede servir de ayuda al problema original y si alguien me sabe dar una respuesta a mi problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Quizá esa publicación en inglés te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500

Comment: Supongo que habrás configurado correctamente firebase y tu app, sobre todo el punto 3: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup